# How do I share the height of a div between three other divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a three div inside another div and I need to share the height of the parent div between the three childs.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="frameright">
        <div class="divright">
            <table class="right" id="andamento">
                <caption style="text-align:left">Em Andamento()</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Chamado</th>
                        <th>Atividade</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Inicio</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>tempo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="divright">
            <table class="right" id="aberto">
                <caption style="text-align:left">Aberto()</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Chamado</th>
                        <th>Atividade</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Abertura</th>
                        <th>Previsão</th>
                        <th>Dias</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="divright">
            <table class="right" id="encerrado">
                <caption style="text-align:left">Encerrado()</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Chamado</th>
                        <th>Atividade</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Inicio</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>Conclusão</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>Tempo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    html{margin:1px;}
    body{font-size:70%;margin: 0px;}
    p{font-size:medium;}
    html,body{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;overflow:hidden;height:98%;}

    table{border-spacing: 1px;}
    table thead tr th{width:2%;background: #2F75B5;font-weight: normal;padding: 2px 3px;color:#FFFFD4;}
    table tbody tr td{z-index:0;background-color:#DDEBF7;min-width:1%;}

    table.right{margin: 5px 0 0 0;max-height: 33%;}
    table.right tbody td:hover {background-color:#79B7E7}
    table.right tbody tr:hover td{background-color: #79B7E7}

    .blue{background-color: #79B7E7}
    .red{background:#F08080;font-weight:normal;}
    .green{background-color:#60CA8F;font-weight:normal;}

    .number{text-align:right;}
```

I want to share the height equally between this three div elements. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Give your parent div height and then share it as percentages,check out the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all give your `parent div` some height like

```
 .frameright{
      height: some_value;
  }
```

Then share it among all your `child divs` as a percentge which is `33.3%` in your case

```
.divright{
    height:33.3%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the parent div to be the height of the window, you could add the following to your CSS:

```
.frameright{ height: 100%; }
.divright{ height:33.3%; }
```